# I want to know :CocSearch /pattern/ -A <number>

Tags: vim, plugins, neovim, coc.nvim

I use Neovim with Plugin Coc

when I use `:CocSearch /some pattern/ with option -A <number>`

with that command, It opens Search results about files of directory

For example

`:CocSearch /some pattern/ -A 20`

**I want to know "-A and number" option meaning**

as far as I know, if I increase the number then I got more relative lines of the result (Vscode has same feature)

But until now I can't find documentation of this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CocSearch` use https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep to do search, `-A` is `rg`'s arg:

```
-A, --after-context <NUM>
        Show NUM lines after each match.
```